# Java Servlet Filter Capture Root Path

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am creating a small servlet project to mock an authentication flow. I am performing authentication with a servlet filter sitting in front of a few JSP pages.

To map the urlPatterns captured by the filter, I am using a WebFilter annotation specified as follows:

```
@WebFilter({"","/gallery.jsp","/welcome.jsp"})
```

From my understanding, the empty string should catch the root path.

So when I enter `localhost:8080/auth-jsp-demo/` into my browser the filter should catch. However, my logs are showing that the filter is not catching the root path.

I am using Tomcat v9 and JDK 11.

Answer (score 1):

Discovered the answer!

It seems the root path is captured in servlets using an empty string in the annotation:

```
@WebServlet("")
```

However, for servlet filters the root path is captured with a backslash:

```
@WebFilter("/")
```